# View in Activity Causes Crash

Tags: android, view, crash

I am trying to use the fullscreen activity layout.  I want the main view to be a custom view.  When I try to add anything creating new view class to the fullscreen activity class it causes the program to crash when run in the emulator.

Do I have to tell the xml file that it is a custom class?  Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

error:02-05 10:11:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unibitri.zoobies/com.unibitri.zoobies.ZoobiesMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.unibitri.zoobies.ZooView

Comment: it causes the program to crash => **Show the crash log or logcat output**

Comment: What is your view / activity code ?

Comment: 02-05 10:11:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unibitri.zoobies/com.unibitri.zoobies.ZoobiesMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.unibitri.zoobies.ZooView

Comment: Show some code and logcat output

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean... You must reference your custom view correctly in your android xml file for the layout. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<packagename.CustomView
  android:id="@+id/customView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Where packagename is something like com.example.myapplication and CustomView is the class name of your custom view

EDIT:
Make sure your constructor for CustomView takes both arguments Context context, AttributeSet attr

```
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

    }
```

Comment: 02-05 10:11:06.231: E/AndroidRuntime(823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unibitri.zoobies/com.unibitri.zoobies.ZoobiesMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.unibitri.zoobies.ZooView
is the error I get... <com.unibitri.zoobies.ZooView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"... is what I have in the xml... the package and class are right?

Comment: Your package and class look correct. Check my EDIT, I think that may be your problem

Answer (score 0):

- check your logcat, it will give you a hint on what happens
- check your custom view code and activity code according to the log